Notational change for linearity condition in analysis of Boolean functions
On Wikipedia, it clearly states that a Boolean function $f: \{-1, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ is linear iff it satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ where $xy = (x_1 y_1, \dots, x_n y_n)$. However, on another page, it is said that:
 which (based on the 4th bullet point) gives the impression that $f$ is linear iff the condition $f(xy) = \frac{1}{f(x)f(y)}$ is met.
I'm reasonably sure that the standard definition that I stated first is correct – so, why is the BLR test on such a Boolean function using a different criteria?

Those are the same criteria. $1$ and $-1$ are both equal to their own inverses.

Sorry – I don't think I could get any dumber than this. Thanks
